# Load primefaces components and pages width ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, primefaces, load, refresh

I would like change web pages without refresh but using ajax for change the page.

I would like use primefaces, but if I use a jquery function like .load('mypfform.xhtml'), if i put a pf component inside, it can't go.

How I could to do something like that?

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Explain it further

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to navigate your pages or try to refresh after any interval of time,
for only page and data refresh try

```
<p:poll interval="30" listener="#{bean.refresh}" update=":form:dataTable" />
```

For navigation try

in faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/signin.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
           <from-action>#{login.submit()}</from-action>
           <from-outcome>Success</from-outcome>
           <to-view-id>/MainPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
           <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{login.submit()}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/signin.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Where

```
@ManagedBean(name = "login", eager = true)
    @SessionScoped
    public class Login implements Serializable {
public String submit(){

 //check for verification

    if(isValid){
       return "Success";
    else{
         return "fail";
    }
}
```